# How to solve this error Value must be ≥ 0 but `getColumnIndex` can be -1

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout

error comes in this code

```
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

String phoneNo=phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
```

```
private ArrayList getAllPhoneContacts(){
    ArrayList<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if ((cursor !=null ? cursor.getCount() : 0) > 0){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
  
            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0){
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id},null);
                while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                    String phoneNo = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    phoneList.add(phoneNo);
                }
                phoneCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    if (cursor !=null){
        cursor.close();
    }
    return phoneList;
}
```

Comment: I did some Googling for this.  It seems that this message is a "analyzer warning" that doesn't prevent your code from trying to run, and your code may run fine even if you're getting this warning.  Does this track with your experience?  Is your code able to run?  Is it giving the right result?  If so, then you might want/need to just figure out a way to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 5):

It is an Android lint warning, not an error. Some options:

1. Suppress the warning with e.g. `@SuppressLint("Range")`
2. Use `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` instead of `getColumnIndex()`. The first throws an exception on missing columns, the latter returns -1.
3. Move the `getColumnIndex()` outside of the `get...()` call and store the index to a variable. That prevents lint from seeing the issue; you can also check for `>= 0` yourself and act accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer!  Nice that you give multiple options for how to suppress the warning. - #2 seems like the most robust solution.  Having all of your query code in a single try/catch that catches the Exception that is thrown by that method would let you nicely deal with missing columns in a single place.